# welcome email devise gem when sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, devise

in user.rb

```
  after_create :welcome_message

  def welcome_message
    UserMailer.welcome_email(self.email).deliver
  end
```

in routes `devise_for :users`

in usermailer

```
  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => user.email, 
        :subject => "Welcome to Vancouver Presales!")
  end
```

I have this error:

> Missing template user_mailer/welcome_email with "mailer". Searched in:
>   * "user_mailer"

please any one tell me whats the wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Missing template user_mailer/welcome_email with "mailer". Searched in:
>   * "user_mailer"

states that it is going to look for template for speciic mailer's method but you have not created yet so you are getting this error. Create template with the `mailer_method_name.html.erb` under `app/views/your_mailer/mailer_method_name.html.erb`

Like this Create Template for `UserMailer` under:

**`app/views/user_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb`**

```
# you can design your template here how it should look when user receive the mail

<h1>Welcome <%= @user.name.present? ? @user.name : @user.email %> to Vancouver Presales! </h1>
....
```

Comment: @nour : Glad to help you.

Comment: @nour : Click the checkmark ✔symbol on the left of this post(answer). (it's right below the arrows) . click on it, it means it is accepted answer by you which solved your problem

Comment: i have another problem, theres no email sent

Comment: @nour : It's better to ask seprate question for each problem. Post new question with your devise and application configration and error you get

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a template having same name as your method name which is sending an email.
So you need to create a template here in directory 
app/views/user_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb
your email content will go in this template